# Using inherited attributes from parent model in laravel

Tags: mysql, inheritance, eloquent, laravel-5.8

#### Using Laravel and MySQL Database

I'm developing a system intended for a doctor-patient management, where there is a parent table **'people'** that includes all the general info of a person such as (name, ssn, phone, .......). then there is *two tables* that inherit this table (**'Patient'**, **'Doctor'**) each one of them has different additional attributes. 

Each person can be either doctor, patient or both.
but will have a different id as doctor and as patient.

**What i'm trying to do is**
Making  Person model that extends eloquent and both
Patient & Doctor Model extends Person.

---

The output i'm hoping for should be like this

the Patient and all the attributes related to him in patient table and the attributes related to him from person table.

---

I can't find a way to call for example the patient with ssn = 1 `Patient::find('ssn')->Person::find('ssn')`to show all the attributes of patient with the related attributes from the parent table 'person' as well such as name, ssn and phone ......etc.

---

**In a simple way i want a way to access the attributes of a person for specific patient.**

---

I tried calling the person first then using the ssn to call the patient with the same ssn. but it felt like a relationship and not inheritance as i put the ssn as foreign key in the patient and doctor table.

---

Is there a way to do it with class inheritance or am i better using relationships and which type "polymorphic or normal" ? and how to call the person model in the patient model?.

Hope you understand what i'm asking.

---

Thanks.

Comment: I think using many-to-many-polymorphic-relations solves the problem. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: Define the relation as *Patient belongs to Person*. Then you can call `$patient->person->last_name`

Comment: But in this case it will be a normal relation not inheritance right?